# vertical-align в webkit

Tags: css

создал собственный шрифт, устанавливаю для него `vertical-align: middle`.

в *firefox*, *opera*, *ie* все работает нормально, в *maxton* и *safari* текст чуть ниже центра.

почему может не работать только в *webkit*?

Comment: Посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793503/how-to-vertically-align-text-across-browsers Может подойдет.

Comment: normalize.css здесь не помогает. вероятно чтото со шрифтом так как другие шрифты правильно выравниваются по центру.

Comment: иконочные шрифты с icomoon как раз и отображаются с неправильным выравниванием на тех браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо, вопрос решен. проблемма была в не обнуленном свойстве `font-size` внешнего элемента..